# Postgres WAL files clean up

Tags: postgresql

Is there any way how I can clean up postgres WAL files ON MASTER SERVER - SLAVE is OK, but master has wal keep segment set to 2000 and this is causing disk space usage to grow.
I'm looking for a way how to clean up that disk space on MASTER without breaking anything.
I know that setting keep segments to 2000 is madness but that was not set by me.

Answer (score 2):

Address the underlying cause and the problem will go away (your underlying problem being someone who didn't know what they were doing and didn't read the Postgres manual set `wal_keep_segments` to an insane value):

1. Reduce `wal_keep_segments` to a sane value.
   (10 is usually sane. 100 is not unreasonable).
2. Restart the Postgres server.

Comment: You don't need to restart postgres, a reload is sufficient. You do however need to run `psql -U postgres -c checkpoint`.

Answer (score 0):

An appropriate value for wal_keep_segments will depend on a number of variables. No one can tell you what to set that to.
I've set our databases to 64, as 64 is the average number of WAL files written during a busy period over 3 hours.
 That would mean I have 3 hours to fix any issue between the Primary and the Standby during this time. If I go past 3 hours I would have to either re-silver the Standby or start transferring WAL files from the Archive directory.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem on a preproduction server that used to be backed up and is no longer. It turns out the configuration had been changed to:

```
archive_command = ''
archive_mode    = on
```

...presumably to remove the rsync command. This resulted in the `pg_xlog` growing endlessly. You cannot change `archive_mode` to off, this requires an instance restart.

I solved the problem by changing `archive_command = '/bin/true'`, did a `select pg_reload_conf();` and the directory was cleared over the next couple of checkpoints.